# DROP DATABASE crash mysql server

Tags: mysql

I've a little problem when I want to DROP my database.

When I execute :

```
DROP DATABASE `mydb`;
```

MySQL returns :

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

(Executed from phpmyadmin, I'm disconnected and redirected to login/password)

The problem can be a fantom table.

If I execute :

```
CHECK TABLE `mydb`.`mytable`
```

I have :

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'mydb.mytable' doesn't exist
```

But if I execute :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`mytable` ...
```

I have :

```
Error Code: 1050. Table '`mydb`.`mytable`' already exists
```

"SELECT *" says it doesn't exist to.

I have tried innodb_force_recovery 6 when I execute the DROP DATABASE :

```
InnoDB: Load table 'mydb/mytable' failed, the table has missing foreign key indexes. Turn off 'foreign_key_checks' and try again.140417 11:09:55 InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 2797190000 in file row0mysql.c line 3683
InnoDB: Failing assertion: table
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/...-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
09:09:55 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=1
max_threads=151
thread_count=1
connection_count=1
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346075 K bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0xffffffffb9523670
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = ffffffffa6b9b32c thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x33)[0xb7329743]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x4a4)[0xb71ca984]
[0xb6e7f400]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(abort+0x182)[0xb6b8bd72]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4e1e3b)[0xb737fe3b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x4c8d6a)[0xb7366d6a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x32ca05)[0xb71caa05]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24plugin_foreach_with_maskP3THDPFcS0_P13st_plugin_intPvEijS3_+0x1d1)[0xb70ac121]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16ha_drop_databasePc+0x3f)[0xb71cbb9f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_rm_dbP3THDPcbb+0xc13)[0xb707b073]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x4477)[0xb709fff7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x254)[0xb70a2f54]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x2000)[0xb70a5910]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0xce)[0xb70a63de]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x123)[0xb7155983]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x50)[0xb7155ab0]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0(+0x5c39)[0xb6e5dc39]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0xb6c34d4e]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (ffffffffb9599500): DROP DATABASE `mydb`
Connection ID (thread ID): 2
Status: NOT_KILLED

The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

Ideas ?

Comment: Does the user have privileges on mydb?

Comment: Try stopping the mysql server and restart it using this command.  **mysqld_safe start**

Comment: I use root so yes I have privileges

Comment: when I use mysqld_safe start I have the same rapport into my syslog than the one I have posted

Comment: Does the related .frm and/or the .ibd file exist in your data directory on the file system (probably /var/lib/mysql)?

Comment: the folder /var/lib/mysql/mydb is empty (no file and no hidden file)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the data file or the .frm file disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to find out a solution for the same problem for days. Afterwards, I solved it by disabling InnoDB. Actually, after disabling InnoDB, I can create the table again as MyISAM. Then I enabled InnoDB. In MySql (MariaDB) log, it still complains about the table that can not be loaded. However, I can work out with the new MyISAM table.

By the way, I dropped and recreated the database but it didn't solve the problem. While dropping database, I have got "connection lost" error. After disabling InnoDB, I successfully dropped the database.

To disable InnoDB,  write the following lines in my.cnf and restart the mysql service.

```
[mysqld]
skip-innodb
default-storage-engine = myisam
```

After recreating the lost table as MyISAM, I enabled the InnoDB.

Answer (score -1):

Please check `max_allowed_packet` value inside `my.ini` for Windows and `my.cnf` for Linux and increase the value then restart the service in-order to take effect. this should solve the problem.

Comment: `max_allowed_packet` is related to TCP/IP packets, and in the OP problem, for sure packets aren't huge.

Comment: max_allowed_packet used to make sure the client did not lost connection when he or she try to execute command that need a lot of memory, the value for the max_allowed_packet is too small even if the parameters doesn't exist on the ini or cnf file. but we can get more info from err file inside the datadir, if the first solution did not solve the issue.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet : _The maximum size of one packet or any generated/intermediate string._ `DROP DATABASE` should not generate any large packet or intermediate string...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/packet-too-large.html the max allowed packet is used when the user try to execute SQL command via client tool or MySQLD

Comment: I've changed the value 16M to 128M and always the same problem

Comment: Please attach the error log file it can be found at the datadir under machine_name.err

Comment: one possible solution that may help you to fix this issue based on the error message: stop mysql service completely and delete ib_logfile (note take a backup from the files first this can be done by copying the files to another directory out of MySQL and the datadir) then start the service again.

Comment: I've stopped the mysql server, deleted /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0 and /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1 then started the mysql server and always the same problem :(

Comment: is this problem happened to you for specific database or for all database? if its for one database I have a work around that will help you to get red of the database (shutdown the SID then delete the database folder inside the datadir then start it again) not the best practice but it worked for me before when I had problem with a dropping database. if its for all databases I need to do some research about this issue :)

Comment: It's only on one database. I've already try to delete the 'mydb' folder but when I tried to rename 'mydb2' to 'mydb' mysql crashed like when I try to drop it. Actually 'mydb' folder is empty (no hidden files to).

Comment: I did some research about this problem and found there is two parameters in the ini or cnf file that may help you to fix this problem: first one (wait_timeout = 28800) and the second one (connect_timeout = 28800) then restart the SID (service) please try and let me if this fix the issue for you (hopefully it dose :)) otherwise I will search again for another solutions for similar issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I put this values in my file /etc/mysql/my.cnf, I restarted the mysql server and nothing... /etc/mysql/my.cnf is the correct file ?

Comment: try this parameter it will minimize the chances of crashing the SID innodb_file_per_table

Comment: There is no reason why a DROP TABLE could fail because of max_allowed_packet. Also, the log clearly shows that the server crashed.